# Problem with adding GeoJSON to OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, geojson, coordinate-system

I transformed (.geojson file)from EPSG 2180 to 4326 using

```
ogr2ogr -f "GML" -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY -t_srs EPSG:4326 test.geojson file.geojson
```

I would like to add to map, but I received this error :

[image]

Below script: 


  
    
    
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    
    OpenLayers 3 example

## My Map

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
       new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
       }),
```

new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
         projection : 'EPSG:4326',
         url: 'gjson/test.geojson'
      })
  })
        ],

```
    view: new ol.View({
      center:[0,0],
      zoom:2

    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The error comes from you GeoJSON file. Show us the content of this file pls.

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/vpapQ/test.geojson here is whole file

Comment: Your file is not in GeoJSON format but in GML. Try to get a proper GeoJSON file.